# Parsing IMage object in JSON

Tags: python, json, image, surveymonkey

How do I insert image object instead of image url in the below code?

payload ={ "headings": [ { "heading": head, "image": { "url": i } } ], "position": 1, "family": "presentation", "subtype": "image" }

Comment: Are you trying to parse image file or pass it across web? Just in-case if you want to edit your question.

Comment: I am trying to upload image in surveymonkey site using python code

Answer (score 1):

Use the files parameter in that case, passing in a dictionary or sequence of tuples. See the [POST Multiple Multipart-Encoded Files](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files)  section of the documentation.